# Can't view list of sites in IIS

Tags: iis, permissions, user-accounts

One of our team members can't see the list of web sites in IIS on one of our servers. When he loads IIS he just sees an [empty Start Page node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOB7P.png). If he right-clicks on the Start Page node, and then on "Connect to a Server", and he puts the name of the server he's logged into he gets an "Access is Denied" error. When I log in to the server I can see the list [no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSt89.png)

We checked with the server admin and both of our user accounts are Administrators. Could this be a permissions issue related to his user account or would this be a setting in IIS itself that needs to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the team member user account is in the "IIS Manager Permissions" page at the websites level? IIS uses very granular permissions in order for a user to view web Sites. Are you using Windows Authentication only?

Comment: We use Active Directory for authentication. The strange thing is we haven't had to edit "IIS Manager Permissions" for any other server that this user has access to. What could cause this server's IIS in particular to require such granular permissions to be set?

Comment: Well, in the "Management Service" you configure IIS to allow remote connections and the type of authentication to use but (to my understanding and experience) this is just for connecting to IIS server, so if you want to allow a user to view the sites you have to add the user(s) in the "IIS Manager permissions" page. If you haven't done it before you can give it a try and see how it goes and leave sites permissions out of the equation.

Comment: I added the user to the IIS Manager Permissions list for a handful of the sites but they still couldn't see these sites or the server node in IIS. I also verified that the Management Service is ocnfigured to allow remote connections. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok Bruno, let's see. Are they using the IIS Manager console (in their local computers) to connect to the server? I think there might be something missing..I use to delegate access to developers and what I did was at server level just add the user account in the IIS Manager users page and then to give them more granular permissions at the web sites level (which you already did). Can you confirm that you add the users at the server level?

Comment: Also use the *Connect to Site* or *Connect to Application* wizard (inside IIS web server) to see if your changes have taken effect for the user account.

Comment: The user was accessing IIS by means of RDPing into the server. I started looking into the IIS Manager Users page but jwe just found out that they server we've been looking at is going to be nuked soon. They gave my colleague a new vm to work with so thankfully this issue has become a moot point. Thanks for all your help though. I tried to upvote your response but don't have enough rep to do so.